# Setup port forwarding without using router?

Tags: raspbian

Can I port forward with software instead of using the router for a Minecraft server? I have the latest pi and Raspbian. I'd prefer it if it were free. Thanks!

Comment: what router are you talking about?

Comment: I have an XFinity Home WiFi router.

Comment: check out port forwarding using uPnP - if your router supports this

Answer (score 1):

You asked if you can use port forwarding but without additional information. To answer it in general: yes you can. Any Raspberry Pi with the Raspberry Pi OS uses **iptables** and with it you can configure port forwarding. For example to forward port 80 to port 8080 on machine 192.168.1.1 you can use:

```
rpi ~$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes, you can through a VPN, however not every VPN supports this and are certainly not free. You could buy a public IP, but then again you're buying something, and at that point you should probably just buy a router that can port forward. So to answer your question directly, no, there's no "easy" and free way to port forward without a router.